# Calculate an angle when there is a log-scale in coordinates

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

that's problem just a question of basic math but i can't figure out where my mistake is.
So i got a logarithmic x axis and a linear y axis.
I have two points A`(centerX, centerY)` and B`(x2, y2)` in my plot, and I want to calculate the angle between the x-axis and vector AB.

I know the x,y value of both points, but if I compare my solution with a calculator i get the wrong value.
I'm using `atan2` in Javascript.
Do I have to normalize my vectors first ?

```
function calcAngle(centerX, centerY, x2, y2) {
  var distY = y2 - centerY; 
  var distX = x2 - centerX; 
  var theta = Math.atan2(distY, distX);

  return theta*180/Math.PI; 
}
```

[image]

Comment: You say you want to calculate the angle *between two points*. What does that mean? You need three points to define an angle. Could you please edit your question with an image of the plot, and the points of interest, and marking the angle that you want?

Comment: `Hallo Stef, I've horribly drawn what i try to reach but i hope it helps.  I just need to get this angle , i know the coordinates of the first and second point

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the angle as seen on your plot you will have to take into account the scaling factors for x and y and - yes - you will also have to calculate the logarithm of the x values.

Something like the following might work:

```
function calcAngle(centerX, centerY, x2, y2, xscale, yscale) {
  var distX = Math.log(x2) - Math.log(centerX); 
  var distY = y2 - centerY; 
  var theta = Math.atan2(yscale*distY, xscale*distX);

  return theta*180/Math.PI; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help , can you please explain me what you mean with the factor xscale and yscale ? i think your solution might help me if I understand what x/yscale is

Comment: xscale and yscale would be the factors that translate x and y values into screen coordinates. These factors are often calculated internally in charting applications but they reflect the ratio between the (raw) data range and the screen space needed to show it.

Comment: I just realized that it was your x-axis that is logarithmic and not the x-axis. I corrected my answer accordingly.